# Sharing desktop with OSX in LAN

Tags: 11.10, remote-desktop, vnc, macosx

I'd like to share Ubuntu 11.10 Desktop to my OSX computer in the LAN. What options there are? I have been using VNC in the past, but I was wondering could I open X server connection directly from OSX?

Also looks like Unity has horribly killed VNC support: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/759349

Also looks like xrdp is no go: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xrdp/+bug/846407

Comment: Is Teamviewer an option?

Comment: Is Teamviewer VNC based?

Comment: Yes it is VNC based but i never had any issues with it even when using the Android version if you have problems with Unity, you can use the Classic desktop as you may know Unity is a compiz Plug in, yet as a comment mentions in the bug you linked.

Comment: There is no Classic desktop in 11.10. However there is something called Unity 2d.

Comment: AH yes sorry i read 11.04 Yes,  use Unity 2D by the way, the bug you linked to mentions that 11.10 should have resolved whatever problems VNC had with slow refresh.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!