# Desktop sharing using router

Tags: mac, vnc

I have a mac running OSX 10.7.4 and a ubuntu machine running 12.04, both connected to the same router. I am able to use desktop sharing and vnc viewer to see my ubuntu desktop from my mac, but it is slow and it takes a lot of bandwidth. So I was wondering if there is a way I can do the same (see Ubuntu from my mac) using the router as an intermediary without using the internet. I checked this post [Sharing desktop with OSX in LAN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60796/sharing-desktop-with-osx-in-lan) but its not very clear to me whether there is an option.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find the IP address of your Linux computer on the local network. You can use the Network Tools program on Ubuntu of if you are comfortable with the command line then you can use run "ifconfig" and look for the inet address. Typically it will start with 192.168.X.X or 10.X.X.X.

Then on your Mac, go to the Finder and type Command-K to open the server connect dialog box and enter vnc:// and the IP address from step one. eg: vnc://192.168.1.2